# Read operation in filesystem

Tags: filesystems, ext4

I have a very dumb question. When a read operation is made, am I doing a write too? I'm thinking about write in journal area because my metadata are changed, like mac time. Is my thinking wrong?
I want to conclude if a write barrier enabled in my ext4 filesystem cannot make significative difference in read operations performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, a write operation is often associated with a read one. There are some differences though. There are no writes if access time update is disabled, and obviously no write either if the file system is read-only. Moreover, these writes are asynchronous being buffered in memory, and actually flushed on disk periodically reducing the impact on performance.

Depending on the workload, you might nevertheless increase the performance of your I/Os by using either the `noatime` mount option or the `relatime` one, the latter being the default with modern kernels.

Comment: Thanks man. But enabling barrier are the writes mentioned asynchronous too?

Comment: I guess so, these writes are not userland writes so they should be unaffected by write barriers.

Answer (score 2):

By default Linux uses the "relatime" mount option for all file systems, which only updates the atime field if it is more than 24 hours stale, or if atime < mtime (since some mail readers use this to determine whether three is unread mail in a /var/mail/XXXX file).    This significantly reduces the number of metadata writes.   There is also the "noatime" mount option, which completely disable the writes.  The relatime and noatime fields technically break POSIX compliance, although most people don't care about strict POSIX compliance these days.

In Linux 4.2 and newer kernels, there is also the "lazytime" mount option, which will update the all of the timestamp fields field in memory (so it is always accurate) while the system is running.   The timestamps on disk is updated (a) when the file system is unmounted, (b) if the timestamps are more than 24 hours stale, (c) if some other inode field in that inode needs to get updated --- e.g., i_size, i_blocks, i_mode, i_uid, etc ----, or (d) (an ext4 optimization only), there is an adjacent inode in the same inode table block which is getting updated on disk.

So the advantage of lazytime is that you get back your POSIX compliance, and it also suppresses mtime updates for non-allocating random writes into a file (e.g., in the case of an enterprise database tablespace file, such as what Oracle or DB2 might use).   However, with lazytime, it's possible ot have one timestamp value while the system is running, and if you crash (as opposed to cleanly unmount the file system), you'll get a different timestamp value after you reboot.   This is allowed by POSIX, which only makes consistency guarantees after an fsync(2) or a umount(2), but it's possible this might surprise some applications.